# .NET portal web clipping/web connector/portlet bridge/web capture analogs

Tags: .net, sharepoint, portal, connector, vignette

We are seeking .Net analogs or ports of what they refer to as "Web Connector" in Vignette, "Web Clipping" in WebSphere, "Web Capture Web Part" in Sharepoint (could not evaluate myself) or PortletBridge http://www.portletbridge.org/features.html.

The implementation itself does not seem to be extremely sophisticated thus porting PortletBridge to .Net seems feasible, however something existing shall be preferred over it. Google did not help a lot in finding one thus posting here, has anyone seen something of a kind?

Comment: Ahh, portals.  I remember them well.  I still have nightmares when I think of uPortal.  What are you trying to achieve here?  It looks like a faily straight forward task to code up ... :/

Comment: Generally speaking, we are seeking a way to proxy parts of intranet applications to other applications that are more broadly accessible and we've observed a 100% desired behaviour in Vignette. We however are in .Net world.

Exactly right, the uPortal implementation is very understandable and by far the only open source that works predictable (greetings to Jahia and PortletBridge). So far the only thing I can't figure out is javascript proxying, for example for Ajax grid pagination.

However, are you aware of the .Net analogs?

Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://spplayground.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebClipping%20WebPart&referringTitle=Home.